# error while running eval.py tensorflow object detection api

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

When I run the eval.py script, the images are evaluated and in the logs I can see that visualizations are also created on the images.

I have set num_examples to 50 in the pipeline.config. However, 50 images are not evaluated. After evaluation of some 9 images (which varies a lot - sometimes 5, sometimes 4), I get an error that `ValueError: Image with id 1531471339_visible.png already added.`

I am not sure where I am going wrong.

Note: This is my own dataset that I've trained. 
I also tried different machines, and still the same error.

eval config:

```
eval_config {
  num_examples: 50
  use_moving_averages: false
}
eval_input_reader {
  label_map_path: "/home/path/to/labelmap.pbtxt"
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "/home/path/to/file.tfrecord"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post your ```.config``` for more detailed help. How many images does your evaluation set contain?

Comment: There are 215 images in the eval set.

Comment: Usually this appears if the dataset is too small for ```num_examples``` and images are used twice. Did you check your eval set  for duplicates?

Comment: Yes, I checked for duplicates. No duplicates found.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error message. I solved it by adding

**metrics_set: "coco_detection_metrics"**

into my config file.

```
eval_config {
  num_examples: 50
  use_moving_averages: false
  metrics_set: "coco_detection_metrics"
}
```

Then the error message disappear... not sure why. Maybe you can give it a go. Let me know if it helps.